# WCF object Type Formatter error

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serialization, soapui

i am using below Data Contract in my WCF service it works when my client is C# console application

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonField
{
    private string _fieldName;
    private object _fieldValue;

    public PersonField()
    {
    }

    public PersonField(string FieldName, object FieldValue)
    {
        _fieldName = FieldName;
        _fieldValue = FieldValue;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return _fieldName; }
        set { _fieldName = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public object FieldValue
    {
        get { return _fieldValue; }
        set { _fieldValue = value; }
    }
}
```

BUT

when i try it from SOAP UI(http://www.soapui.org/) i get the following response

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter entities. The InnerException message was 'Element FieldValue from namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entities.Person cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

can't i use a type object in WCF?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried but I think you cannot. If the entity is of type object, then the contract cannot be clearly specified because you cannot know the type in advance, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For SoapUI it does not know what types could be in `object`. You have to define the known types so that the schema (WSDL) exposes them to SoapUI. Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

You should have something like

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Type1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Type2))]
public class PersonField { ... }
```

Comment: that object FieldValue could be , int or date or string or list of another object so do i do 
[KnownType(typeof(int))]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
[KnownType(typeof(DateTime))]
[KnownType(typeof(object))]????

Comment: Possibly. The MSDN link states it is for deserialisation and perhaps since the expected type is not in the WSDL SoapUI cannot determine what it should be. For a test just add one known type and then send that through to see if SoapUI can handle it.

Comment: Regardless of getting SoapUI to work you have to also think what are the consumers of your service. If you dont sepecify what type could be on that field then no client will be able to deserialise it.

Comment: tried adding
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(int))]
    [KnownType(typeof(DateTime))]
    [KnownType(typeof(string))]
    [KnownType(typeof(double))]  didn;t work